# Vuetify @click not work when swipe/zoom-in/zoom out in mobile browser,I'm not sure what kind of gesture it is

Tags: vue.js, click, vuetify.js, gesture

vue:2.6.10
vuetify:2.1.13

describe:
Vuetify @click not work when  swipe/zoom-in/zoom out in mobile browser,I'm not sure what kind of gesture it is.
if code isn't in codepen but in the clear dev mode,is it more easily reproduce.usually when i swipe down,swipe up,and it happens.

[here is my codepen demo](https://codepen.io/tzr164/pen/PowzZbQ)

People please give me some inspiration.

```
<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-list subheader>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item avatar ripple @click="rssHandler()">
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-avatar>

              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>rss</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>

              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Touch events` from Web Api.
Link on MDN Web doc's - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events
So, for example, if you want to trigger event on touch end it will be:

```
<v-list-item avatar ripple @touchend="rssHandler()">
```

Comment: Thanks,it works for me.I want  vote to you,but my reputation is not  enough.thanks a lot.